# How to remove indent from the second numbering level ?

Tags: html, css, html-lists

I have problem to remove indent on the elements 2.1 , 2.2 , 2.3 etc... probably the third numbering level indent will be moved to left after solving that problem.

My code:

```css
ol {
  counter-reset: item
}
li {
  display: block
}
li:before {
  content: counters(item, ".") " ";
  counter-increment: item
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two
    <ol>
      <li>two.one</li>
      <li>two.two</li>
      <li>two.three</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li>three
    <ol>
      <li>three.one</li>
      <li>three.two
        <ol>
          <li>three.two.one</li>
          <li>three.two.two</li>
        </ol>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li>four</li>
</ol>
```

I tried a lot of ways, but nothing is not correct. Someone do have idea , how to solve that, please?

Comment: Do you want third level indent or not ?

Comment: Ofcourse , now I realized, that indent of the third numbering level will be mandatory, too. Amazing solution, thank you so much ! :) :)

Answer (score 1):

Add these styles

```
ol ol {
  padding: 0;
}
ol ol ol {
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```css
ol {
  counter-reset: item
}
ol ol {
  padding: 0;
}
ol ol ol {
  padding: 20px;
}
li {
  display: block
}
li:before {
  content: counters(item, ".") " ";
  counter-increment: item
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two
    <ol>
      <li>two.one</li>
      <li>two.two</li>
      <li>two.three</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li>three
    <ol>
      <li>three.one</li>
      <li>three.two
        <ol>
          <li>three.two.one</li>
          <li>three.two.two</li>
        </ol>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li>four</li>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you can't change the markup, you could apply your styles to the list's parent element and target the second numbering level using the child combinator (`>`):

```css
.list-parent > ol > li > ol {
  padding-left: 0;
}
.list-parent ol {
  counter-reset: item
}
.list-parent li {
  display: block
}
.list-parent li:before {
  content: counters(item, ".") " ";
  counter-increment: item
}
```

```html
<div class="list-parent">
  <ol>
    <li>one</li>
    <li>two
      <ol>
        <li>two.one</li>
        <li>two.two</li>
        <li>two.three</li>
      </ol>
    </li>
    <li>three
      <ol>
        <li>three.one</li>
        <li>three.two
          <ol>
            <li>three.two.one</li>
            <li>three.two.two</li>
          </ol>
        </li>
      </ol>
    </li>
    <li>four</li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

This would be the best approach concerning maintainability as well, as applying global styles to every `<ol>` list on your website would only result in unwanted behavior sooner or later.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an easy solution:
(See the comments in the code)

```css
ol {
  counter-reset: item;
  padding-left: 0;   /* Remove the padding of all ol elements */
}
ol ol ol {
  padding-left: 1em; /* Set the padding of third level ol elements */
}
li {
  display: block;
}
li:before {
  content: counters(item, ".") " ";
  counter-increment: item;
}
```

```html
<ol>
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two
    <ol>
      <li>two.one</li>
      <li>two.two</li>
      <li>two.three</li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li>three
    <ol>
      <li>three.one</li>
      <li>three.two
        <ol>
          <li>three.two.one</li>
          <li>three.two.two</li>
        </ol>
      </li>
    </ol>
  </li>
  <li>four</li>
</ol>
```

Hope it helps.